# Sharepoint 2010: Viewers not able to see the jquery slide plugin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Sharepoint 2010: Viewers not able to see the jquery slide plugin but if adding user to owners group they can see the slider. I have also checked the jquery plugin files have been published as major version.

Comment: Is the page where pluging is used also published?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm probably the Viewer group doesn't have permission to you Jquery files. Try double checking each required JS files also css file it's being used if atleast they have view permissions to it

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could check things below:

1. Check if there is unique permission in the jQuery file.
2. Delete, re-upload the jQuery files and publish the files as the major version.
3. Disable the version to check if the users in the viewer group can see the jQuery files.
4. Grant the user with viewer permission directly to check if the same issue will occur.